# how to pass a substring or single character within datagridview

Tags: c#, string, winforms, datagridview, pass-by-value

How can I pass substring or a single character within the datagridview.
For example: I have a string like 'animal?species'  I need to pass 'animal' to another cell of the datagridview, how can I do that ? 
Any help would be great, thank you.

**EDIT:**

```
private void keypress1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 || dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57 && e.KeyChar==8 ) {}
            else
            {                   
                e.Handled = true;                    
            }
        }
        if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex==4)
        {
            string test = "";
            if (e.KeyChar == 92)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value = null;
                //dataGridView1.Columns["dom"].ReadOnly = true;  bad code
                test = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                string[] splittedtest = test.Split('?');
                for (int i = 0; i < splittedtest.Length; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[7].Value = splittedtest[i];
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

when it comes to `test = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();`  nullexception occurs. I guess the reason is value are not submitted yet.

Comment: does your string have always '?' mark?

Comment: It may have ? or it may not, it will be up to user,  I can handle '?' with keypress event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with 'Split' function. this may give you a hint to proceed.

```
string test = "animal?species";
string [] splittedtest = string.Split(new Char[] { '?', '\' },
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//string[] splittedtest = test.Split('?');
for(int i = 0;i<splittedtest.length;i++)
{
   // do your stuffs like below,  
   // DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[X].Text = splittedtest[i];
   // where X is the column you want to read. 
}
```

Comment: I tried I'm encountering with nullreference exception. 
Also I realized that I need to be more specific with my question, 
I'm sorry about that I edited my question can you take a look at it?

Comment: @BarisY Why you are doing this    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value = null;   ?

Comment: because this cell is actually contains the domain cell, and cells[4] is username cell. if user inputs this   'DomainB\Baris' to cell 4  if there is previously assigned value in cell[7]  need to be deleted and replaced with DomainB

Comment: I know this is something unnecessary but professor does want that property in the project

Comment: then make it as dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value = "";. It will do the same as you want. And instead of doing this DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[7].Value = splittedtest[i];  try this DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[7].Text = splittedtest[i];

Comment: split saves these characters comes after  specified character - in my situation '\' , how to save character comes before '\'  ?
EDIT: I'm sorry I just realized that.
                    string a = splittedtest[0];
                    string b = splittedtest[1]    this will complete

Comment: @BarisY Check my answer now. I have changed a bit as you want.